# Silent installation of AddIn in Outlook

Tags: windows-10, outlook-addin, code-signing-certificate

Is there a way to get a silent and trusted installation of an AddIn to MS Outlook *without* a certificate or a warning dialog showing?
 
It’s my customer's IT dept who opposes to installing certificates.

We’re working in a Win10 Environment.
We bought, and used, a code signing certificate, prior to the IT dept request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a dialog you need to install the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on machines, see [Manage Trusted Root Certificates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You may find the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) article helpful.

Note, MSI allows to install software silently. See [How to install a .MSI file unattended](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ilikesql_by_dandyman/2013/03/10/how-to-install-a-msi-file-unattended/) for more information.

You should be able to use the /quiet or /qn options with msiexec to perform a silent install. MSI packages export public properties, which you can set with the PROPERTY=value syntax on the end of the msiexec parameters. For example, this command installs a package with no UI and no reboot, with a log and two properties:

```
msiexec /i c:\path\to\package.msi /quiet /qn /norestart /log c:\path\to\install.log PROPERTY1=value1 PROPERTY2=value2
```

Also you may consider deploying the plug-in using GPO (group policy objects). Read more about that in the [HowTo: Install a COM add-in automatically using Windows Server Group Policy](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/01/25/automatic-installation-windows-group-policy/) article.

Comment: ...install the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store, not for the local user, but for the local machine of course ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course - a certificate is required only if you are using VSTO. If you create a pure COM based addin (IDTExtensibility2 etc.) addin, Outlook would be perfectly fine.